# Angular: HTML Table handle check/uncheck/check all

Tags: angular

Using Angular 6:

I have a HTML table with data and one of the row is a checkbox where either the users can select individual row or use select all checbox in header to select all rows.

```
  <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <a>
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="masterSelected" name="list_name" value="m1" (change)="checkUncheckAll()" />
          </a>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let c of data">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="c.isSelected" value="{{c.name}}" (change)="isAllSelected()">
        </td>
       <td>other td data goes below</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  Below is my Angular component code:

  export class GridComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data: any[] = [];
  allSelectedData: any[]=[];

   checkUncheckAll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      this.data[i].isSelected = this.masterSelected;
    }
    this.getCheckedItemList();
  }
  isAllSelected() {
    this.masterSelected = this.data.every(function (item: any) {
      return item.isSelected === true;
    });
    this.getCheckedItemList();
  }

  //Method called when checbox is checked and to update the array
  getCheckedItemList() {
    this.checkedList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      if (this.data[i].isSelected) {
        this.allSelectedData.push(this.data[i]);
      }
    }       
    //Calling my service observable to store the data which other components can subscribe to
    this.myService.setSelectedData(this.allSelectedData);
  }  
 }
```

Just posting the relevant code above.

When the user selects a single row by clicking the checbox or by selecting all the rows I am using this.allSelectedData to hold the selected data.

Everything works fine here. The issue comes when the user unchecks the selected value I am not sure how to remove that from my this.allSelectedData.

DO I have to loop through everything again and check individual values or if there is a better way to do so.

What I am looking for is that this.allSelectedData should hold all the selections. If someone checks new rows then add to this, if someone unchecks a row then update this to remove that entry.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this, here is that row which user selecting from front end.

```
singleSelecttion(row){
this.selectAllItems=false;
row.isSelected =! row.isSelected;
if(row.isSelected ==true){
    var index = this.selectedRowArr.map(function(item){
        return item.Id;
    }).indexOf(row.Id);
    if(index== -1){
        this.selectedRowArr.push(row);
    }
}
else if(row.isSelected ==false){
    var index = this.selectedRowArr.map(function(item){
        return item.Id;
    }).indexOf(row.Id);
    if(index != -1){
        this.selectedRowArr.splice(index,1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do I need to add above? Can you provide details according to the code which I have.

Comment: see below example with desc

Answer (score 0):

I do this, i hope to help you.

1. Use array `selectedIds` save selected item, it is also very suitable for use when submitting data.
2. When selected an item：

```
select(id) {
  const index = this.selectedIds.indexOf(id);

  if (index !== -1) {
    this.selectedIds.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    this.selectedIds.push(id);
  }
}
```

3. Do this `selectedIds.indexOf(item.id) !== -1` when check an item selected state.
4. Do this `selectedIds.length && selectedIds.length === data.length` when check all selected state.
5. When you click the `selectAll` button:

```
selectAll() {
  if (this.selectedIds.length && this.selectedIds.length === this.data.length) {
    this.selectedIds = [];
  } else {
    // there you need get every item'id, so do map
    // Can be optimized here, if selectedIds has it's id, just skip it...
    this.selectedIds = this.data.map(item => item.id);
  }
}
```

> 1. `selectedIds` and `data` both maybe is 0, so need `selectedIds.length && ...`.
> 2. `this.selectedIds.length && this.selectedIds.length === this.data.length` can be written as a `getter` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
//function here parameter row is yor selected r unselected row
singleSelecttion(row){
// all item selected false
this.c.isSelected = false;
// masterSelected toggle the value if true then false, else false then true
row.masterSelected =! row.masterSelected;
//you have to add a key isSelected in yor data each row, when data comes add a isSelected key by default false. 
if(row.isSelected ==true){
// selectedRowArr is a array in which value push or pop, here id is unique key
    var index = this.selectedRowArr.map(function(item){
        return item.Id;
    }).indexOf(row.Id);
    if(index== -1){
        this.selectedRowArr.push(row);
    }
}
else if(row.isSelected ==false){
    var index = this.selectedRowArr.map(function(item){
        return item.Id;
    }).indexOf(row.Id);
    if(index != -1){
        this.selectedRowArr.splice(index,1);
    }
}
```

its just an idea try to customise this code according to you

Comment: If you see my code I am not passing any row from my grid. I am calling isAllSelected() when individual row is selected and calling checkUncheckAll when all checbox at header is checked.